# iOS Universal Links / Android App Links when email server changes URL

Tags: android, ios, ios-universal-links, android-app-links

I am having some troubles with my universal links in iOS and App Links in Android when the email server add a redirect to the URL of the email.

For example, we have a service that sends an email to reset your password.  I want that password rest to open the app if it's installed to do the reset.  Our corporate email finds the URL in the email and replaces it with a urldefense url.  So clicking the password reset goes to urldefense an redirects to the correct url.  This "sort" of works in android, but never in iOS.  Another example is that outlook/hotmail seems to add an embedded browser of sorts so that doesn't work in android or iOS.

Anyone come across the best way to handle such scenarios?  Seems silly to have such a powerful linking tool, yet not account for the fact that most email providers are not using spam/security measures on URLs embedded into emails.

Comment: You may need to see if your email scanner can whitelist the relevant URL.

Comment: that would only help for my company email though right?  Gmail, hotmail, etc would still add the redirects

Comment: Maybe. The other approach is to redirect to send them to a page on your website that redirects to the universal link.  Ugly but it will work 100% of the time.

Comment: I don't think apple will honor the redirect... that's what's already happening with the safe link redirect unfortunately

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question? I'm also frustrated by App Links / Universal Links. It looks like it's just implied, that we're always going to use a direct link. But I see how many apps use marketing links in their email and it still opens the app. I wonder, how they do this, because it literally doesn't work for me.

Comment: @KyryloZapylaiev no luck... I started investigating services to handle it, but never got any further.  If I ever get back to that I will post an update